# CSS full width menu with dropdowns underneath their respective entries

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jimbeeer/2fjxzcru/3/)

I have a full width css menu that stretches the whole screen but I can't work out how to get the respective subnav items to sit underneath their parents.

Can it even be done? 
I can't find anything online that let's me do exactly this but surely it's possible, isn't it?

The number of top menu items needs to be variable, so regardless of how many there are, it would stretch accordingly.

Link to the JSFiddle above to see what I've got so far.

html:

```
<div class="nav">
      <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/home.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/products.php">Products</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="sublink"><a href="/content/products.php">Sub Products</a></li>
            <li class="sublink"><a href="/content/switchboards_distribution_panels.php">Switchboards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/solutions.php">Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/case_studies.php">Case Studies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/downloads.php">Downloads</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/careers.php">Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/content/contact.php">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
ul#css3menu1,ul#css3menu1 ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    z-index:5000;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:0px 0 0 -13px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>ul{
    display:inline-block;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover li{
}
ul#css3menu1 li{
    display:table-cell;
    /*white-space:nowrap;*/
    font-size:0;
    color:#000;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover{
    z-index:1;
}
ul#css3menu1{
    font-size:0;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
    zoom:1;
    padding:0;
    *display:inline;
}
* html ul#css3menu1 li a{
    display:block;
}
ul#css3menu1>li{
    margin:0;
}
ul#css3menu1 .link a:active, ul#css3menu1 .link a:focus{
    outline-style:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 .link a{
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#777777;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:23px 9px 24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.4s;
    border-right:1px solid #eef1f1 !important;
  letter-spacing:0px;
}
ul#css3menu1 .link a:last-of-type{
    border-right:0;
}
ul#css3menu1 .link a.selected{
    background-color:#E4E8E8;
}
ul#css3menu1 .link a:hover{
    background-color:#E4E8E8;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul li{
    float:none;
    display:inherit;
    margin:10px 0 0;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul ul{
    margin-left:-10px;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul a{
    text-align:left;
    padding:4px;
    font:14px Tahoma;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed{
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 span{
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:0px;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 ul li a.pressed{
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst>a{
    border-width:0;
}
ul#css3menu1 li.toplast>a{
    }
```

Comment: Simply add `position:relative;` to your `.link` class. Absolute positions are based on the next element up the chain with explicitly stated positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't really your code or what's possible. It's how CSS references an origin point for `position: absolute`.

Origin values like top/left are based on the next parent element with a specified position value. If there isn't an explicitly positioned element in the chain, the origin is based on the `<body>` element.

```
|||| Element with position: absolute
||| - parent
|| - parent position: relative (this X/Y is used to position the element)
|
```

You just need to give your nav containers positioning. Here's an example:

*(note: I'm using flexbox to align the menu to make life easier in the example, `ul` & `li` will work too. Also, put the hover on the container so that moving to the sub-content will keep the menu open.)*

```css
nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navItem {
    flex-basis: 1;
    background: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative; // this is important to have
}

.navItem span {
    display:block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.subNav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; // push to bottom of container
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #555555;
    color: #ffffff;
    display:none;
}

.navItem:hover .subNav {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="navItem">
        <span>Main Nav</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navItem">
        <span>Main Nav</span>
        <div class="subNav">
            <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 1</span>
            <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 2</span>
            <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 3</span>
            <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navItem">
        <span>Main Nav</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navItem">
        <span>Main Nav</span>
        <div class="subNav">
                <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 1</span>
                <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 2</span>
                <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 3</span>
                <span class="subMenuItem">Sub 4</span>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navItem">
        <span>Main Nav</span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: To be honest, your brief comment was absolutely perfect. I just didn't think of using position:relative. But i've got it working now exactly as i want. It's a solid thank you from me. This particular thing has always driven me crazy as I've never got it perfectly right.

Comment: @jimbeeer I'm glad it was helpful. That issue has bothered me so much that I now include `*{position:relative}` in my CSS reset. The times its annoying to have every element default to that are way less frequent than the times it helps like in your example.